# Using AndNav tiles storage as input for OpenLayers.TMS

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, mobile-atlas-creator

Is there a possibility to use map tiles from AndNav (created wit Mobile Atlas Creator) that are in format:

Mapnik\12\2241\1369.png.andnav (I know that 12 is the zoom level but don't have idea what is 2241 and 1369...)

as an input for OpenLayers.TMS layer?

I found information that I could use local tiles with TMS: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles

Unfortunatelly, I can find any place where AndNav map format is documented and reading sources didn't helped me too much.

Would anyone could help me?

Comment: Does it need to be andnav? mbtiles + openlayers (or leaflet), with or without TileStache is a nicer combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should check out OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ for your cache. U can find more information in net.

Tile machanism is

```
Z - zoom level
X - folder name
Y - image name
```

your url is z/x/y.png and dont forget to check out geturl function too

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I didn't try that but it sounds like the way I should do this. Thanks!